# MYSQL Update Status if Category is Contained In Second table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables:  food t1 and categories t2 and a variable within t1 called 'ingredient'
the categories table contains a list of categories such as fruit or vegetable

i.e.  this is table 2 for example

```
ingredient | category
---------------------
apple | fruit 
broccoli | vegetable
```

I want to run an UPDATE query on the status

i.e.

update set status = [ result from t2 ]
where
ingredient = [ matching ingredient from t2 ]

So if a record in t1 had 'ingredient' = 'broccoli - it would SET the status variable to 'vegetable'

What is the syntax using inner join, left join for this pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your tables is somewhat uncölear

```
Update table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON tabl1.ingredient  = taböe2.ingredient 
SET table1.status = table2.categories
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. I think you got my meaning. Let me try that. For the post, do you have a better way of explaining this question so that it is more clear what I'm getting at? I think you understood my pseudo code.

Comment: a good question has a [mre] with create tables insert data and a fiddle link so that we can see on the first glance, what the query must look like, your question is basically understanble, but the structure is not clear of both tables a nd i had to read it over and over again

Comment: I see your point, however the actual data, actual tables and actual example is far more complex than I'm reducing here to a public post.  Thanks for that MRE.  Is there a post you've written I can look @ that has the proper format?

Comment: yes a [mre] is a reduced form a your tables like in your example with the essential columns only like your example shows it is only very unclear how the structure actually is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update food t1
INNER JOIN categories t2 ON t1.ingredient  = t2.ingredient 
SET t1.status = t2.category
;
```